# How to change the geometry of the two selected models?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I know getSelection() is get the db id of seletion model.

but after this i don't know how to control this viewer.

There are two windows selected by the viewer.

I want to change the geometry of the two windows.

Forge Viewer is open Revit file by my bucket.

```
viewer.getSelection()
=>(3) [3043, 3055]//how to?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the viewer isn't designed to support geometry modification. You *can* modify your design elements in these ways:

- changing their position, orientation, or scale ([blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/working-2d-and-3d-scenes-and-geometry-forge-viewer))
- hiding them, and potentially inserting your own custom three.js geometry instead ([tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/custom-geometry/))
- changing their materials, incl. using custom shaders ([blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-shader-materials-forge-viewer))

But if you actually need to tweak the individual vertices of the mesh geometry, that would be very difficult to do.

Comment: Is there a way for the viewer to change the family of Rabbit in real time?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Once your design (whether it's Revit, IFC, DWG, Inventor, etc.) is converted by Forge for viewing in Forge Viewer, it's just a specialized viewing file format, kinda like when you convert Word or Excel documents into PDF. So there's no concept of "Revit families" anymore.

Comment: If you'd like to change Revit families of individual objects in your Revit design, you'd have to use the [Design Automation for Revit](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/), and that wouldn't be in realtime.

Comment: It helped me a lot. Thank you.